# What's the difference between <input type="button" /> and <button>?

Tags: html, button

I didn’t know about the `<button>` tag until today.

Comment: Most importantly, does it work in all browsers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, `<button>` is more flexible as it can contain other tags inside it. Like,

```
<button type="submit"><strong>Click</strong> me, <em>user!</em></button>
```

You won't be able to do this with regular `<input>`.

Answer (score 8):

Check this article

[Inputs vs Buttons](http://particletree.com/features/rediscovering-the-button-element/)

> Buttons created with the BUTTON
>   element function just like buttons
>   created with the INPUT element, but
>   they offer richer rendering
>   possibilities: the BUTTON element may
>   have content. For example, a BUTTON
>   element that contains an image
>   functions like and may resemble an
>   INPUT element whose type is set to
>   “image”, but the BUTTON element type
>   allows content.

Answer (score 0):

You can include images in a `<button>` tag, but not in an `<input>` tag, amoung other differences

Comment: Not true. `<input type="image" />`

Comment: You can include more than one image in a ``<button>``

Answer (score 0):

See: [W3C site](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5).

They are very similar but the `<button>` tag has a few extras that can be useful on the odd occasion.