# Why the handle in JQuery UI slider is <a> tag?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I was reading the code in the official demo page for slider: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/ and I was wondering why an `<a>` tag is used for handle? Why not a `<div>`?

```
<div class="demo">

<div id="slider" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-hover" href="#" style="left: 19%; ">
    </a>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: changing it to a div in chrome inspector kills it, possibly because it removed event handlers.

Comment: I don't know why with `<a>`. but `<div>` is a block element, which doesn't suit here.

Comment: I thought so too, but because `position:absolute` it is has `display:block`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they used an anchor because in HTML links are what separate HTML from other markup languages because they provide interaction. Taken from w3c

> HTML offers many of the conventional publishing idioms for rich text
>   and structured documents, but what separates it from most other markup
>   languages is its features for hypertext and interactive documents.
>   This section introduces the link (or hyperlink, or Web link), the
>   basic hypertext construct. A link is a connection from one Web
>   resource to another. Although a simple concept, the link has been one
>   of the primary forces driving the success of the Web.

And the handle is also something you click, so maybe they thought that semantically made more sense using an `<a>` instead of a `<span>`.

To make it clear, my thought is that they could have used anything technically but they choose an anchor for semantic reasons

Comment: Still it doesn't make sense. `<a>` is for links, `A link is a connection from one Web resource to another,` the handle connects nothing to nowhere. I think the go-to non-semantic interaction element is the `<button>`, but people have long been using the `<a href="#">` since it's way easier to customize—but `<button>`'s are just [as](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314989/can-i-make-a-button-not-submit-a-form) [customizable](https://gist.github.com/2946234).

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering the same ... so here I am ... with a theory!

The handles need to be able to **have the focus**
(when they do, you can use the arrows, Home- and End-keys to manipulate the handles)

Not sure if spans or divs **can** have the focus (in all browsers..) ?

Maybe `<button>` could be used instead ?  (somebody, please try)
- that would make more sense. And not clutter up the status-line : (
(Could we get into trouble, if there's a surrounding form without a proper submit-button ?)