# html: using buttons in forms witout action

Tags: html, forms, button

I'm styling links as buttons, and have noticed that the link action is overridden by the form action. So a cancel button actually updates. Is there a way to remove this behaviour easily and reliably(across all browsers) from the button, while keeping it inside the form element? Or do I need to restyle the buttons?

---

update:

```
<form>
 <input type='text'>
 <a href="cancel"><button>cancel</button></a>
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

right now the `a>button` has the same action as `input(submit)`

---

ended up restyling and removing the `button` tags

Comment: Can you include your HTML ...

Comment: Can you post an example? As far as I know, the only button that should trigger the form action is `<input type="submit">`

Comment: What do you mean, "a cancel button actually updates"?

Comment: yes, the action of the `<button>` to submit precedes the execution of the link

Comment: There is no need for extra links and buttons in this case. That's what `<input type='reset'>` is there for. It resets your form and you can hook into the `reset` event.

Comment: I just found the question asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314989/can-i-make-a-button-not-submit-a-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the way links work, when you click `<a href="cancel">`, it will try to navigate the browser to that resource. (e.g. http://yoursite.com/cancel).

If you want your button to do some JS action, remove the `<a>`. It's just redundant in this case. Style the `<button>` how you want it.

If you want your button to navigate to a page, remove the `<button>` and style the `<a>`.

Comment: that's what I was afraid of having to do.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to do this? Nesting a button in a link doesn't make much sense...

Comment: I was using a template for quick prototyping. Now I've gone and styled the links to not use buttons, luckily most of the links are generated using a function(anticipating that I'll be changing the styling) so It's a quick change. I'll have to go through the code and replace the instances where I used the button tags.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I have the wrong end of the stick here but I am not entirely sure I understand your question as that cancel button shouldnt be submitting your form, you are however using buttons incorrectly which may be the source of your problem.

I think if you do it the way you are doing it they wont work in IE:

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onClick="window.location='http://www.yoursite.com/cancellink'" />
```

If you do them as above should do whatever you want in all browsers unless js is disabled - hope this helps
Instead of linking to a page you could call any js function inther to clear form or whatever you want

Comment: While the js being disabled is unlikely, having the button do the exact opposite when it is disabled seems too risky.

Comment: I agree if that is the case but it shouldnt submit the form without js - it shouldnt do anything

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the type of the button, by default button act as a submit button inside a form if type attribute is not set.

```
<a href="cancel"><button type="button">cancel</button></a>
```

Comment: why, who knows - MS engineers?   how - the button doesn't do anything

Comment: I always use `<input type="button">` to reduce confusion

Comment: Seems a know issue in IE, check workaround here http://www.expertsguide.info/2010/07/button-tag-inside-anchor-not-working-in-i/