# What causes $.ajax to result a full post-back

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

Could someone tell me what causes a **$.ajax 'POST'** request to result a full post-back (full page refresh)?

I'm using the $.ajax 'POST' in the **ASP.NET MVC** context, where the view is calling the controller method (which returns a JSON result) through a $.ajax 'POST' request.

The code is below.

---

```
// View.
<button id="save" onclick="saveClick()" />
```

---

```
// View.
<script type="text/javascript">

    function saveClick() {
        if (!$("form").valid()) {
            return false;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action(@MVC.Ticket.ActionNames.SaveTicket, @MVC.Ticket.Name)'
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(getJsonTicket()),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data.SaveResult);
            }
        });

        return true;
    }

    function getJsonTicket() {
        ...
    }

</script>
```

---

```
// Controller action.
public virtual JsonResult SaveTicket(Ticket newTicket)
{
    try
    {
        TicketManager.SaveTicket(newTicket);
        return Json(new CreateTicketViewModel {SaveResult = "success"});
    }
    catch
    {
        return Json(new CreateTicketViewModel { SaveResult = "error" });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you returnung a partial view? Can your show your AJAX call and controller action as well!

Comment: Please provide some sample code so that we can take a closer look.

Comment: i couldnt understand what do you mean with, "causes a $.ajax 'POST' request to result a full post-back (full page refresh)"

Comment: maybe not calling `preventDefault` in case that you are calling $.ajax in click event of an anchor tag.

Comment: @Simon, the code is added

Comment: I guess you're working with T4MVC?! Your AJAX call is calling /Name/Create and not /Name/SaveTicket

Comment: And beside your AJAX call isn't replacing anything, so ther must be something else going on.

Comment: @M.Nour Berro : I expected a partial page update [in this case no page update as controller action passes only a JSON] from the AJAX-POST, but the full page get refreshed.

Comment: @Simon yes T4MVC it is, it's a copy-paste error, which now corrected.

Comment: @oomlaut, the code is added

Comment: Are you somewhere binding an event to `$('button')` or `$('#save')`. Ajax call looks fine. Provide some more details.

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili, its a button click that triggers the floor.

Comment: @Simon, there are no others event assignments to this control. But i must mention this #View was opened as a **jQuery UI Dialog Form** by a different #View. Would this have an effect?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do

```
<button id="save" type="button" onclick="saveClick()" />
```

to make sure form is not posted by this button.

**Explanation:**

The default value for the type attribute of button elements is "submit".

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3315016/1014281

Comment: Tied it, same result. But I did one thing, removing the html `<form>` tag, did manage to stop the full post-back while the rest of the functionality works as required. But this is not the perfect solution as the `<form>` tag is required by the **jQuery Validation Plugin**. Simon, do you see any workaround? Thank you.

Comment: Sweet! that did the charm. Could you please tell me how this fixed the post-back?

Comment: Makes perfect scene. Thanks again Simon.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that you are using a `<button>` and not `<input type="submit">`? Because if you don't prevent the button from submitting it will submit the form (full postback).

`<input type="submit" onclick="return saveClick()">` should work as long as `saveClick()` always return false.

Comment: Yes it's a button. Yet along I added `return false;` to the end of `saveClick()` function, but the same result. In a different attempt, I removed the html `<form>` tag, did manage to stop the full post-back while the rest of the functionality works as required. But this is not the perfect solution as the `<form>` tag is required by the **jQuery Validation Plugin**. Do you see any workaround for this? Thank you.

Comment: you have to have "return" in the onclick attribute too

Comment: Apparently I was missing the `type="button"` in the button tag. Adding it fixed the problem. Thank you Jonas.

Comment: the `onclick="return saveClick()"` should work too. (instead of the type)

Comment: Yes you are correct. As you mentioned then the method must always return false **or** call the method as: `onclick="saveClick(); return false;"` Thank you Jonas.

Answer (score 1):

you must add `type="button"` to your `button` tag