# How can I set a Button's type to "Button" (as opposed to the default "Submit") in C#?

Tags: c#, dynamic, sharepoint-2010, submit-button

According to an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314989/can-i-make-a-button-not-submit-a-form), I can prevent a button from submitting the form by setting its type value to "Button", like so in HTML:

```
<button type="button">Cancel changes</button>
```

...but how can I do this in C#? I am creating my controls dynamically, something like this (pseudocode, as I'm away from my IDE):

```
button btn = new Button 
             {
               CSS = "bla"
             }
btn.Type = "Button"; // <- something like this?
```

Comment: what's the type of property ``Type``??

Comment: you can also add UseSubmitBehavior="false" to an asp:Button control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [HtmlButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlbutton(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of Button if you want the "HTML button tag"

```
var btn = new HtmlButton();
btn.Attributes["class"] = "bla";
btn.Attributes["type"] = "button";
```

Button renders `<input type="submit" />` and Button.UseSubmitBehavior renders `<input type="button" />`.

HtmlButton will render `<button type="YOUR_DEFINITION"></button>`.