# Vue - button on click submits a form

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component where a user can upload an image, and I would like to also add a feature of removing an image. I have added a button which removes the current image, but the problem with it is that the form is getting submitted as well, and I would like to avoid that. I just need to remove the current image if it exists. This is the script:

```
<template>
    <div class="Image-input">
        <div class="Image-input__input-wrapper">
            <h2>+</h2>
            <input @change="previewThumbnail" class="Image-input__input" name="image" type="file">
        </div>

        <div class="Image-input__image-wrapper">
            <i v-show="! imageSrc" class="icon fa fa-picture-o"></i>
            <img v-show="imageSrc" class="Image-input__image" :src="imageSrc">
            <button v-show="imageSrc" @click="removeImage">Remove image</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {

  props: ['imageSrc'],

  methods: {
    previewThumbnail: function(event) {
      var input = event.target;

      if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        var vm = this;

        reader.onload = function(e) {
          vm.imageSrc = e.target.result;
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
      }
    },
    removeImage: function removeImage(e) {
        this.imageSrc = '';
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I have tried with placing `event.preventDefault()` in the removeImage method, but then, if I after removing image try to upload the same one again it won't upload. Not sure what to do about it?

Comment: Try `prevent` [event modifier](https://vuejs.org/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers)

Comment: After I have removed the image and try to immediately upload the same image, it still won't upload. Every other scenario works, only this one doesn't.

Comment: Will you be able to create a working JSfiddle for the problem?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you have a button inside a form, it has a default type of "submit". To prevent that from happening, you will have to set `type="button"` as follows:

```
<button type="button" v-show="imageSrc" @click="removeImage">Remove image</button>
```

Reference: [Can I make a <button> not submit a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314989/can-i-make-a-button-not-submit-a-form)

**Edit: Solution for the second problem mentioned in comments #1 to #5**

Please modify your `reader.onload` function as follows:

```
reader.onload = function(e) {
    vm.imageSrc = e.target.result;
    console.log("Clearing file input");
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type=file]').forEach(element => {
        element.value = "";
    });
}
```

As you can see, I am printing out a console log for debugging (which you can remove), then proceeding to select all file inputs and resetting its value. This clears the selected file.

**Note:** This clearing function happens after the file is read into memory. If you want it on remove function, you can do as follows:

```
removeImage: function removeImage(e) {
    this.imageSrc = "";
    console.log("Clearing file input");
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type=file]').forEach(element => {
        element.value = "";
    });
}
```

The choice is yours, whether you want to clear the file name after reading into memory or if you want to keep it on screen. Let me know if it works!

**Another note:** If you have any other `<input type="file">` in your app, even that will get cleared. But I assume you would have read it into memory and kept it in some local variables. To avoid this, you need to modify the `document.querySelectorAll` function to target only the relevant input by giving it a class or id.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that works! But then I have another problem which is after I remove the image and try to immediately upload the same image, it still won't upload. Every other scenario works, only this one doesn't.

Comment: Yes, I could reproduce your problem locally. I copied your code into a local file, and added `console.log("Got new image");` as the first line of previewThumbnail() function. In this, I can verify that the second attempt is not working as expected. Will get back if I can find a solution.

Comment: From what I can see, the old file is still kept as "chosen", and the first file name is displayed. What we need is a way to clear the form after reading the image as data URL.

Comment: Yes, I am not sure how to do that, I am unfortunately not that good with javascript. If you have any solution for it, I would be very thankful! Thanks in any case!

Comment: This looks very interesting... I am allowed to upload a totally different image and it works normally. After uploading *image1.png*, I can remove and upload *image2.png*. After removing *image2.png*, I can go back to *image1.png* without any issues. It is only the same image that is not getting uploaded, probably because that file is already in a chosen state. Still debugging as this is going to affect my app also later, I will get back if I can find a way.

Comment: Yes, exactly that problem! Thank you for your effort!