# Default buttons shouldn't trigger 'field required' alert

Tags: php, html

I have a form containing the following:

```html
echo"<textarea name='pb' required></textarea>";

echo"<button name='bt'>button1</button>";
echo"<button name='bt'>button2</button>";
echo"<button name='bt'>button3</button>";
echo"<button name='bt'>button4</button>";

echo"<input type=submit name='submit' value='Submit'>";
```

As you can see in my code, the textarea is required, but I have many buttons. I want only when I press the submit button that the message that the textarea is required is displayed, but when I click the other buttons this message shouldn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `type="button"` to the buttons should do the trick:

```
<button name="bt" type="button">button</button>
```

See MDN for more about buttons: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

> `submit`: The button submits the form data to the server. **This is the default if the attribute is not specified**, or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.
>
> `button`: The button has no default behavior. It can have client-side scripts associated with the element's events, which are triggered when the events occur.

Answer (score 0):

Phorturin is correct. As stated in [this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314989/can-i-make-a-button-not-submit-a-form) buttons have a default type of submit [(see the html spec for more info.)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-button-type) If you set the type to button for your 'bt's, then they won't submit your form.