# Ajax Call Is Not working properly for a specific if else statement of a particular query

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Here is my code.I am pretty sure my code is right but it is not functioning properly just for the last query.All the remaining queries are working well and fine but the last query is not returning value back with some object which is not accessible however the updation of table is occurring . What is wrong?
I am attaching the pic of the error being displayed.Error Image

[image]

First the code for frontend page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" id='dat'>
<button id='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
<script src = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.js">
</script> 
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
       var x=$('#dat').val();
       $.ajax({
           type:"GET",
           url: "promo_code_apply2.php",
           dataType: "json",
           data: { x : x },
           success: function(result){
               alert(result);
           },
           error: function(e) {
            // Handle error here
               console.log(e);
           }
     });
   });
});
</script>
</body>
```

Now the code for backend :

```
            <?php
        include('connection.php');
        include('functions.php');
        $p_code=$_GET['x'];
        $sql="select * invite_codes where promo_name='".$p_code."'";
        $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        if(!$res)
        {
            $data=mysqli_error($con);
            echo json_encode($data);
            die();
        }
        else{
        if(mysqli_num_rows($res)==0)
        {
            $data="Invalid Code";
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
        else{
            $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
            $ph=$row['user_mob'];
            $sql2="update user_signup set no_of_referrals=no_of_referrals+1 where promo_name='".$p_code."'";
            $res2=mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
            if(!$res2)
            {
                $data=mysqli_error($con);
                echo json_encode($data);
                die();
            }
            else
            {
            $data="Conngrats";
            echo json_encode($data);
            }
        }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Click on "Network" and look at what is returned from backend.

Comment: Small point with php returning json: this is the proper way to do it `header('Content-type: application/json');`
`echo json_encode($value);`

Comment: Another point you probably shouldn't do is this: `var x=$('#dat').val();` and then further down the line in your jQuery ajax you do the following: `data: { x : x }` this is confusing

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set your button type and as it is inside the `form` its default type is submit. When your button is pushed your `jQuery` event handler is called, but after its completion the default action is called which is submit form action. It reloads your page and your `jQuery` handler wont get data back from `PHP`, because `JavaScript` state resets after reload. 
In order to prevent this behaviour you can either:

1. Put `return false` at the end of your `jQuery` event handler - like this:

   $(function(){
       $('#submit1').click(function(){
       ...
        });
        return false; // <--- prevents default action
      });
   });

or

2. Set button type `type="button"`

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but `<button>` without `type="submit"` shouldn't submit a form.

Comment: Topicstarter didn't set `type` attribute of his `button` element. "The default value for the `type` attribute of `button` elements is `submit`". - taken from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314989/can-i-make-a-button-not-submit-a-form

Comment: According to the linked post `type="button"` should also work. But i'm confused why there is an output in the console.