# JQuery .val is not working

Tags: jquery, html

I've got a problem with my jquery. Before you mark this as a repeated question, I've looked through a bunch of similar solutions and found no answer. What I need to do is simple. I have an input of type number in between two buttons, plus(+) and minus(-). Basically, if you click the plus the value of the input is added by 1 and subtracted by 1 if you click the minus.

Here's my Code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#plus").click(function() {
    var pages_val = $('#pages').val();

    if (pages_val < 0) {
      pages_val = 0;
    } else {
      pages_val += 1;
    }

    $('#pages').val(pages_val);
  });

  $("#minus").click(function() {
    var pages_val = $('#pages').val();

    if (pages_val <= 0) {
      pages_val = 0;
    } else {
      pages_val -= 1;
    }

    $('#pages').val(pages_val);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="minus">-</button>
  <input id="pages" name="pages" type="number" value="0">
  <button id="plus">+</button>
</div>
```

The html is all enclosed in form tags btw. So my problem is when I click any of the buttons the value flickers(blinks) for a second then reverts to an empty input. I checked the code inspector and the value doesn't change. I need the value to remain when the user clicks any of the buttons. Please help. The console shows no logs.

Edit: Who gave my post a  -1 without a solution. It's only been up for 6 sec

Comment: The snippet you gave us is not behaving in the manner that you said it was in your question.

Comment: _“The html is all enclosed in form tags btw”_ - and that’s what causes the problem, because your _submit_ buttons _submit_ your form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I make a <button> not submit a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314989/can-i-make-a-button-not-submit-a-form)

Comment: no, it doesn't when i try it. Something else must be interfering or your shared code is incomplete. And yes, jQuery's `val` works so far.. please stop with these "is not working" titles.. gets boring.

Comment: It is actually redirecting to the same page as you mention you are using form . So when submitting the form it should be something like $(form).on('submit',function(e){ e.preventDefault() }

Comment: Actually, I don't understand why you need this! You can use input type="number" and use min and max attributes to limit the value range. For preventing form submissiion and reload you can simply change the button type="button"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Primary Problem

> *"...any of the buttons the value flickers(blinks) for a second then reverts to an empty input."*

The code provided from OP has form controls wrapped in a `<div>` rather than a `<form>` tag. The following demo presents a more accurate layout since it was mentioned:

> *"The html is all enclosed in form tags btw"*

### Problem

[**A `<button>` tag behaves as a submit button when it is nested within a `<form>` tag**](https://css-tricks.com/use-button-element/). So what happens is whenever a button is clicked, it is interpreted as a `"submit"` event and the `<form>` tag data is sent to a server if configured to do so, and if not configured, it will be attempted regardless. Each submit, failed or successful incurs the `<form>` to be reset.

### Solution

**In order to prevent this reset, add this to each `<button>` tag:**

```
type="button"
```

---

## Possible Problem

Because of the OP code being somewhat error prone and a bit inaccurate, there may be some misinterpretations. Upon initial inspection of OP code, the plus <kbd>+</kbd> button was concating values rather than incrementing a number.

#### Plus Button Clicked 3 times

**Result:** 0111

**Expected:** 3

**Note:** If the minus <kbd>-</kbd> button is clicked after clicking the <kbd>+</kbd> button ***without refreshing the code***, it will function properly as expected, which is decrementing the value as a real number. ***But if clicked when the `<input>` has a value of 0, it does nothing***.

### Explination

***Any `value` derived from a form control (e.g. `<input>`, `<select>`, etc.) is a string not a real number.*** So when 3 clicks of a plus button gives you this:

```
0111
```

That's a string value concat from 4 strings:

```
"0" + "1" + "1" + "1"
```

### Solution

The string value must be converted to a real number value. There are many solutions already presented by other answers posted for this question, so I will just suggest what already implemented in the Demo below:

**Instead of using:** `value +=1` and `value -=1`

**Use this in/decrementing operators:** `value++` and `value--`

Under many circumstances, `+=1` can be misinterpreted as:

```
 (this is a string) `value` (so concat) `+` (this string to it) `"=1"`
```

Whereas this operator: `value++` has no ambiguities because it auto typed to a real number:

```
 (this is a string) `value` (***But*** convert it to a number) `++` (and add it to the default value of number 1)
```

The string value: `"=1"` would normally concat to `=1` literally but since the OP code is using `<input type='number'>`, only numbers (*in the form of a string*) remain while non-number types are removed. Hence: `0111` instead of `0=1=1=1` value for the `<input type='number' value='0'>`

**[Details on JavaScript Data Types](http://www.dyn-web.com/javascript/type/)** and specifically **[++](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_())** and **[--](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Decrement_(--))**

### Demo

```js
$(function() {
  $("#plus").click(function() {
    var pages_val = $('#pages').val();

    if (pages_val < 0) {
      pages_val = 0;
    } else {
      pages_val++;
    }

    $('#pages').val(pages_val);
  });

  $("#minus").click(function() {
    var pages_val = $('#pages').val();

    if (pages_val <= 0) {
      pages_val = 0;
    } else {
      pages_val--;
    }

    $('#pages').val(pages_val);
  });
});
```

```html
<form>
  <button id="minus" type='button'>-</button>
  <input id="pages" name="pages" type="number" value="0">
  <button id="plus" type='button'>+</button>
</form>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. This solved my problem completely.

Answer (score 4):

`.val()` will return the value as a string. You're doing math operations, so you need to turn your value into a number. Try `parseFloat()`

```
var pages_val = parseFloat($('#pages').val());
```

Answer (score 3):

Your +/- was wrong use "++" and "--"

```js
$(function(){
    $("#plus").click(function(){
        var pages_val = $('#pages').val();

        if (pages_val < 0){
            pages_val = 0;
        }
        else {
            pages_val++;
        }

        $('#pages').val(pages_val);
    });

    $("#minus").click(function(){
        var pages_val = $('#pages').val();

        if (pages_val <= 0){
            pages_val = 0;
        }
        else {
            pages_val--;
        }

        $('#pages').val(pages_val);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <button id="minus">-</button>
    <input  id="pages" name="pages" type="number" value="0">
    <button id="plus">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I recommend putting an explanation of what you've changed, not just showing code.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a string, the string will concatenate instead of performing addition.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#plus").click(function() {
    var pages_val = Number($('#pages').val());

    if (pages_val < 0) {
      pages_val = 0;
    } else {
      pages_val += 1;
    }

    $('#pages').val(pages_val);
  });

  $("#minus").click(function() {
    var pages_val = $('#pages').val();

    if (pages_val <= 0) {
      pages_val = 0;
    } else {
      pages_val -= 1;
    }

    $('#pages').val(pages_val);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button id="minus">-</button>
  <input id="pages" name="pages" type="number" value="0">
  <button id="plus">+</button>
</div>
```

The + operator has multiple function when used with strings it will concatenate  them (add them together). When you use it with numbers it will add them. In your application the `$('#pages').val()` was a string. Therefore the + operator performed string concatenation on it which results in values like 11, 111, 1111 etc.

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned in other answer you must use `parseInt()` because `val()` give you a string
and about the buttons not working thats because the default type of buttons is submit so you need to add button type

```
<button type="button" id="minus">-</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been answered but here's what I was playing with (it combines your .click functions)
https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/7L01eu2y/

```js
$('.changerer').click(function() {
  var pages_val = $('#pages').val();
  if ($(this).hasClass('minus')) {
    if (pages_val <= 0) {
      pages_val = 0;
    } else {
      pages_val--;
    }
  } else {
    pages_val++;
  }
  $('#pages').val(pages_val);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="changerer minus" type="button">-</button>
  <input id="pages" name="pages" type="number" value="0" min="0">
  <button class="changerer plus" type="button">+</button>
</div>
```