# How does preventDefault and type submit work with forms?

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, form-submit

So I tried a couple of things when I using JS and try submitting inputs, and there are odd things I didn't understand the logic.

1. There is a difference between `<input tpye="submit/>` inside and outside of `<form>` tag. If it's inside the form tag I need to use `preventDefault()` function, but if it's outside form tag I am not required to do that if write simple js vanilla code.
   Why is that?
2. What the difference between onsubmit and onclick ? especially in a form tag. Because If I use onsubmit the js code doesn't really work.
3. If I use `preventDefault(event)` it's preventing from the form to be sended into a server, and instead it doing the calculations with the browser only ?

Thanks !

Comment: Please show your code. It sounds a bit confusing. A submit button inside a form will submit the form and needs to be stopped to do so, outside not. Makes sense, no?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent form from being submitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted)

Comment: @GoranStoyanov Actually not, it's just saying it prevents the submitting. Maybe I just don't understand what "prevent submit" means.  Is it prevent form to be sent to the server and instead the calculations happening on the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you have a `type="submit"` input (**Note**, [The default value for the type attribute of button elements is "submit"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3315016/11518920)) inside a form, the default action on click is to submit that form. To prevent it from submitting, place the button outside the `</form>`. This works because the button doesn't refer to any form to submit. You can instead, add a listener and call [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).  This works because you are telling the browser NOT to take the default action (submitting the form)
2. `onsubmit` is used mostly on `<form>` elements. It triggers right before the form is submitted regardless of how it is submitted. `onclick` can be emitted from just about any element. It occurs when you click on an element. This could be on an `<input>`, a `<button>`. or even an entire `<form>`
3. Don't use this.

Comment: Thank you very much. If I prevented a form to be sent into sever, how the js code still works. Who does all the calculations? the browser?

Comment: @lirsim What "calculations" are you referring to? If you would like to manually submit the form you can do this by calling `form_element.submit()` or you can use AJAX but that is a more complicated route not in the scope of this question.

Comment: @lirsim If this (or the other) answer solved your problem please click the check mark next to the answer to mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2):

By default, if you have an input of type "submit" in a form then clicking that input (or hitting enter after filling in ANY inputs in the form) will send a post or get request to the server, redirecting the current page to the server's response.

This was the original way to submit form data to a server, without using javascript. If you want to prevent this from happening, you can either replace the submit input with a plain button (`<button onclick="doSomething()">Submit</button>`), or prevent the default submission event: (`form.onsubmit = event => event.preventDefault()`).

The difference between `onsubmit` and `onclick` is that `onsubmit` only fires when a submission event is emitted from the form. To emit a submit event, the form needs an `<input type="submit">` to be clicked, or for the user to trigger a submission by hitting enter.

Another way to prevent this default behavior is to `return false` in the submission handler.

`onclick` only gets fired when an element is clicked. Because events in javascript propagate up to parents, this will also trigger any `onclick` handlers on all parent elements.

If you want to completely ignore the default form submission behavior, then you can define a button with an onclick handler to handle your custom submission logic.

Comment: Thank you very much. If I prevented a form to be sent into sever, how the js code still works. Who does all the calculations? the browser?

Comment: Yes, you will have to implement the submission logic yourself (eg: getting values from form inputs and doing something with these values).