# javascript why i cannot appendchild to html div using javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

i need to append a child control to html element using javascript, the problem is that the child is appear when call the function and disappear directely the child must be in a form tag

this is the code when i append child to the html elemet

```
<html>
 <body>
  <form  >
<button onclick="create()">Create Heading</button>

</form>

    <script>
  function create() {
    var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    h1.textContent = "New Heading!!!";
    h1.setAttribute('class', 'note');
    document.body.appendChild(h1);
  }
</script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

the element `h1` is added to the layout appear and disappear immediately but when i remove the `<form>` it works perfectly

Comment: no idea, reduce it to a [mcve] first? the code mostly looks fine (albeit violating JS naming  conventions all over the place) except for `options.text`, which should be `options.textContent`, and `for ... in ...` for arrays, which you should _never_ use, and should be `for ... of ... `, or `arr.forEach(...)`.

Comment: the select element is filled and displayed correctely but disappeared after millisecond seems like the page is refreshing

Comment: Probably you add your select to the dom element (`tab_logic`) generated and controlled by one of the JS frameworks like React or Vue?

Comment: no i didnt use this in my code , this is the div i want to add element to it   `<div class="form-group" id="tab_logic">`

Comment: again: we don't know, because you're not telling us everything. Please go an take the time to form a [mcve]. Usually, while reducing you discover the problem all on your own and you don't even need us, but if the problem is still there _after_ full reducing, now we can help, because what you're telling us is _the only details_ that matter. Right now, that is very much not true.

Comment: i create a simple example and i will update my question

Comment: please check the question again, the problem is that i cannot add element inside `<form>` tag, it work when i remove form

Comment: also a form action would usually be in the form tag eg. <form onclick="create()"> so adding it to the button suggests form isn't needed, why does it have to be in a form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the form element is submitting when you press the button, refreshing the page and making the header disappear.
You should probably ask yourself: should I really need a form? Are there some inputs that should be handled by the server?

If you really need it, then you can try to [prevent the form from submitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted/34347610)

Also, as pointed out in [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314989/can-i-make-a-button-not-submit-a-form) you can prevent the button to submit the form by specifying its `type` as 'button'.

Answer (score 1):

**Agreeing with @Drago96** Form submits and page refreshes.

What is the point of the `form`. if you are only appending an element

```
<body>
    <button onclick="create()">Create Heading</button>
    <script>
        function create() {
            var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
            h1.textContent = "New Heading!!!";
            h1.setAttribute('class', 'note');
            document.body.appendChild(h1);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```