# Why is one element with custom directive triggering another elements change event in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-forms, angular-event-emitter

I have a form below with multiple elements.
One element is an input with a custom directive for getting google location data. The other element is a file upload element.

When I enter in a value (in focus) in the top element and press enter, it triggers 'fileChangeEvent()' event in the #fileInput element.

I'm having a hard time understanding why?

FYI - I tried changing

```
(change)="fileChangeEvent($event)"
```

to

```
(click)="fileChangeEvent($event)"
```

and it still gets triggered

Form -

```html
<form [formGroup]="editForm">

  // pressing enter, with this element in focus, triggers fileChangeEvent($event) in #fileInput element below
  <input #city appGooglePlaces (onSelect)="setAddress($event)" formControlName="city" class="form-control google-place-input">


  <button (click)="fileInput.click()" class="btn btn-yb w-100">Upload Photo</button>
  <input type="file" #fileInput (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" />

</form>
```

Comment: have you tried: `$event.stopPropagation()`?

Comment: but it shouldn't be triggering another elements change event to begin with...why is it? Do I have something somewhere else that could be triggering it?

Comment: if I comment out '<button (click)="fileInput.click()" class="btn btn-yb w-100">Upload Photo</button>' than it doesn't get triggered when I hit return in the top element, but then the button isn't there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314989/can-i-make-a-button-not-submit-a-form), I think your problem is your button is in a form therefore the default action for the enter key is to submit the form. By default your button is type "submit".

Comment: thanks! I didn't realize the default for a button was submit!!!!!!!