# How to abort submit of <button> tag without "type" attribute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I understand that  without "type" attributes are submitted inside "form" tag. ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314989/can-i-make-a-button-not-submit-a-form))

One of the third-party react components I use has a button that doesn't have a type attribute, which causes it to be submitted unconditionally.

Is there a way to stop submitting a form if there is such a button in a third party component?

This code is just an example:

```
import React from "react";
import {SamethingComponent} from "samething-package";

export const MyComponent = () => {
    
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        // doSomething.
    }
    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                {/* Component containing a button with no type attribute */}
                <SamethingComponent/>
                {/* This is needed as a normal submit button. */}
                <button type="submit">Submit!</button>
            </form>
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: Why don't you `return false;` from the `onSubmit` event?

Comment: @SanishJoseph There is also a submit button.Do I have to determine which button was pressed in onSubmit?

Comment: @Yuwaz I gather that you have to submit the form only if the form submit button is clicked. No other button should allow that, right?

Comment: You can just add onClick to your submit button. Use state for your form elements. And get all the form values in your onClick event.

Comment: In that case, can HTML5 validation such as require attribute be used?

Answer (score 0):

The default type for a `<button>` is `submit`. Setting `type='button'` should prevent it from submitting when clicked and turn it into a regular button.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.
However, buttons on third-party components that I didn't make can't prevent submitting.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onSubmit` of the parent form.

```html
<form onsubmit='event.preventDefault()'>
  <button>Click me with impunity</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<form id="form">
 <input type="text"/>
 <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
const form = document.getElementById("form")

form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault()
})
```

You can prevent all form submission in the form element by calling **preventDefault** on event object.